# phpMyAdmin: How to check if field has index?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

It might be very obvious but I don't know how to check if a field has an index with phpMyAdmin.

It's probably so obvious that nobody ever asked it so I could not find something in Google either.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: this should be best answer

Answer (score 6):

In the phpMyAdmin area, go to the table you want to look at.  Open it's Structure.

Under the list of columns, there is a seperate table that lists the Indexes.

For what it's worth, usuaully, when you create a table, you give it an ID field.  Something that is an auto-increment, and a primary key.  It will automatically index that field.

At least, my host does that.  I cannot verify that all hosts act that way.

Comment: This is correct. By default, the list is collapsed (there's a plus sign in front of "Indexes"; clicking the text will expand it). To make it open by default, see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_InitialSlidersState